# Exporting a web page to PDF

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using a third party library for exporting a page to PDF which is working well for Desktop and its showing the divs properly aligned as per the UI.
For instance, if there are two divs in one line, the PDF also has the same layout.

However, when i am accessing the same web page on mobile, the divs on the PDF go one below the other as the UI on mobile. 
Is there any way by which the PDF for desktop and mobile appear the same?

I have created a simple HTML of the divs.

```css
.divClass{
  display : inline-block;
  width : 100px;
  border : 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  margin : 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divClass">
  <h1> First</h1>
  <p> First Div content</p>
</div>

<div class="divClass">
  <h1> Second</h1>
  <p> Second Div content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a lack of info in this question. Which library are you using for exporting to PDF? What have you already tried? Any errors? Which problems have you faced to achieve what you are trying?

Comment: What do you have in your HTML viewport metadata tag?

Comment: I have used PD4ML Library for exporting the web page. I tried adding Media Queries and it still doesnt work. But I wanted to know if  there is any other way apart from Media Queries.